# How to set Cookie in PHP after <HTML>

Tags: php, html, cookies, setcookie

This is the FULL HTML code that being ran off my site; I want to use the cookie I got from another site on my site to serve as an authentication cookie. right now I can't set cookie on the URL it outputs an example of how i want the cookie to come out in HTTP Header: [Example Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUfwo.png)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://releases.flowplayer.org/7.0.2/commercial/skin/skin.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.flowplayer.org/media/css/codepen.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/7.0.2/commercial/flowplayer.min.js">        </script>
<script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/hlsjs/flowplayer.hlsjs.min.js">    </script>
</head>

<style>
.flowplayer {
background-color: #0084ef;
}
.flowplayer .fp-color-play {
fill: #eee;
}
</style>

<body>

<script>

window.onload = function () {
flowplayer("#hlsjslive", {
splash: true,
embed: true,
autoplay: true,
ratio: 9/16,
hlsjs: { 
  xhrSetup: function(xhr) {
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
  } 
},
clip: {
  live: true,
  sources: [
    { type: "application/x-mpegurl",
      src: "<?php

$expire = time() + 2592000;

$proto = 'http://';
$domain = 'nlds16.cdnak.neulion.com';
$path = 'nlds/nba/nba247/as/live/ipad.m3u8';
$key = '0326ebdb3e654166a66d3c62';
$params = 'expires='.$expire.'&access=/nlds/nba/nba247/as/live/*';

function h2b($str) {
$bin = "";
$i = 0;
do {
    $bin .= chr(hexdec($str{$i}.$str{($i + 1)}));
    $i += 2;
    } while ($i < strlen($str));
    return $bin;
}

$hash = hash_hmac('MD5', $params, h2b($key));
echo $proto.$domain.'/'.$path.'?hdnea='.$params.'&md5='.$hash.'&nltid=nba&nltdt=6';

?>" }
  ]
}
  });
};

</script>

<div align="center"></div>


<div id="hlsjslive" class="fp-slim fp-mute is-closeable"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

I want to Set-cookie to act like authentication:

```
<?php
$name = 'X-NL-SK-nlds-nba-nba247-as-live';
$value = 'FJsmSPq%2Fb%2Fuc1mg3XEUVTCmpch6EwNny1T%2BUC73GMMgfLLyuX%2FAFdbfa31JySSsjoKSyzSrmysXRv%2Bl3TpFlRV3NAaygVw2hZqm76uD8UhwZqFOWNEMGNa9qT7pEHEVL'
$expireDate = time()+86400;
$path = '/';
$domain = '.neulion.com';
$secure = false;
$httponly = true;
setcookie( $name, $value, $expireDate, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try `header("Set-Cookie: name=user......");` ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm looking for a workaround as well, What about checking the validity of the link that's being echoed? If you have managed to solve it, Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a cookie **after** outputting to the page, you must use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). Here is the [basic usage](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.basic.php) example.

Comment: Doesn't work I added
<php

ob_start();

Setcookie...

ob_end_flush();

and got back: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...

Comment: Notice that the error says "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent". When you output anything to the page, you've already gone too far. The first code you posted, I see an echo happening. You can't send header information after you echo (read: output) to the page. Your setcookie() needs to happen before any echo/print/etc.

Comment: Can you update your code in the first post so I see what's going on?

Comment: Is the code in "this is the code I'm running" a PHP file that you are calling? I saved that code into test.php, ran the file in a local server and I'm not getting any errors, and it shows the link on the page for me.

If you are calling any other PHP scripts, I would need to see those, too.

Do keep in mind, however, that typically you have **all** of your output happening between ob start and ob end/get.

Comment: No that's a raw php script, you said you had no errors, were you able to see the NBA stream?

Comment: I told you that you have to setcookie() before outputting, or ob_start() before you output. Your HTML tags happening before any PHP is already outputting to the page.

You've got 2 options: Move the setcookie() function up above the HTML and then you won't need output buffering, OR move ob_start() above the HTML, do all your stuff, then ob_end_flush is the very last thing that happens (after all the HTML)